# How to access the check box values in JSP

Tags: jsp

I am very new to JSP and I have the following issue:

I have to get the values of checkboxes that are checked and make use of these values in Java

In my approve.jsp I have a function called validateApprove() which is called when a button is clicked.

```
function validateApprove() {
    var cc= document.getElementsByName('imagecheckbox');
    var j=0;
    var values = new array();

    for (var i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) { 
        if(cc[i].checked == true) {
            values[j]== cc[i].value;
            j++;
        }
    }

    if (j==0) {
        alert("please check atleast one item");
    } else {
        alert("Are you sure? Do you want to approve " + j + " item(s)");
    }
}
```

the error I get is:
ReferenceError: array is not defined

Why is that error thrown? Can I use array in Java like the following way:

```
String vals[] = request.getParameterValues("values");
```

Comment: var values = new array(); can be defined as var values = [];

Answer (score 1):

Mistake in

```
var values = new array();
```

Should be

```
var values = new Array();
```

`A` not `a` in array declaration.

### See also

- [Array in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateApprove() {
    var cc=[];
    var temp =  document.getElementsByName('imagecheckbox');
        cc.push(temp);
    var j=0;
    var values = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) { 
        if(cc[i].checked == true) {
            values[j]== cc[i].value;
            j++;
        }
    }

    if (j==0) {
        alert("please check atleast one item");
    } else {
        alert("Are you sure? Do you want to approve " + j + " item(s)");
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.